# How to force a click event when an item in a dropdownlist is clicked

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

When an item in my dropdownlist is clicked, it needs to take some action. Current SelectedIndexChanged event is triggered every time it is back to the page without changing the selection in the dropdownlist. I am thinking to add a click event so it can actually take the action whenever the item is actually clicked. However, dropdownlist doesn't have the click event. Is there anything I could do to force a click event in it?

Comment: Where is your code

Comment: are you needing to do something client side or server side? You mentioned its already doing a postback so if you need to do something client side then add the onclick to the server side with a function call. in page_load on every postback add this... DropdownList1.Attributes.Add("onchange", "return callfunction()"); This will call a javascript function on the client side. If you return false from the function it will cancel the postback.

Answer (score 2):

i am not sur about what you're trying to achieve but here is a simple example to trigger a function everytime a dropdown item is clicked

```js
function log(event){
  console.log(event.target.text)
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#" onclick="log(event)">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="log(event)">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="log(event)">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is a wise solution however, the dropdownlist control is already in the existing project so I shouldn't change it. Also the physical button shouldn't be there.